# uptime.exe crashing on Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, monitoring, availability

Can anyone get uptime.exe to run either the /s or /p:n switches on a Windows Server 2008 box without crashing?

I realise it's a NT tool and no longer supported, but it worked fine on 2003.  I've heard there's a version included in Server core, so I was wondering if that works better on 2008?

If uptime.exe is a no go, what do you use instead to get the system availability history?

Comment: Running x86 or x64?

Comment: Same problem on x86 and x64.

Answer (score 1):

Using WMI:
http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/ScriptCenter/en-us/a20766d2-6cc8-4d70-920e-c14506bf53a6

Comment: That just gives me the uptime of the local computer.  I can get that by running systeminfo.  This script http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.12.heyscriptingguy.aspx?pr=blog is better, but again it's for a local machine (but it can be modified), but still a little clunky compared to uptime.exe

Answer (score 1):

I use psinfo out of the PSTools suite.  I haven't tested on 2k8, but it seems to get regularly updated by the author, who now works for Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

You can get this information via SNMP on most devices, so I would expect you can do so with Server 2008.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Start -> Run: `cmd /k net statistics server`. Look for line **Statistics since** - that is your uptime.

Also see this [site](http://www.petri.co.il/check-uptime-in-server-2008.htm) for even more possibilites.

Comment: That still doesn't give the statistics the uptime /s gives.  This is an example of that output:  

Since 8/26/2009: (Last 90 Days)

           System Availability: 99.5496%
                  Total Uptime: 89d 23h:45m:21s
                Total Downtime: 0d 9h:46m:17s
                 Total Reboots: 5
     Mean Time Between Reboots: 18.08 days
             Total Bluescreens: 0

This works fine on Windows Server 2003, but crashes on Windows Server 2008.

Answer (score 0):

I agree entirely with fenster. uptime /s gives far better statistics than the alternative suggestions. It's not just the current uptime period we're interested in, it's all the other info that uptime /s supplies. Try running it on a 2003 server and see what we mean.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this utility:

UPTIME2.exe

http://techibee.com/tools/say-hello-to-uptime2-exe-alternative-for-uptime-exe/1728